# Delayed Expansion in a for loop processing paths that contain exclamation marks

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I know there are already a few questions here about this same issue but I am new to batch scripting and I found those solutions hard to apply in my scenario or directly not applying to my script.
A solution seems to be to temporarily disable `DelayedExpansion` but if I do so then nothing works anymore.

What the script below is trying to accomplish and it works except for the paths with **`!`**, is the following:

It will take a source folder and file by file, including subfolders, check if the file exists in a destination folder. If the file does not exist then it can do two things:

- Copy the file from the source folder to the destination folder, if it is a png, jpg or mp4
- Create a dummy file (a 0 bytes file with the same name and extension) in the destination folder if it is not a `.png`, `.jpg` or `.mp4`. I use for this xcopy (I copy an existing zero bytes file and rename it) because it is the only way I had no issues with special characters.

```bat
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

rem Set the source and destination folders
set "src=L:\folderS\sub1\sub2"
set "dst=L:\folderD\sub1"

rem Set the path to the dummy file that we need to create dummy files with xcopy
set "dummy=L:\dummy.txt"

rem Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
if not exist "%dst%" mkdir "%dst%"

rem Loop through all the files in the source folder
for /R "%src%" %%f in (*) do (

     rem Get the file path
     set "filePath=%%f"
     echo the full path is !filePath!

     rem Get the file extension
     set "ext=%%~xf"
     
     rem Get the relative path excluding the path until the specified src folder
     set "relPath=!filePath:%src%\=!"
     echo the relative path is !relPath!
     
     rem Check if the file does not exist in the destination
     if not exist "%dst%\!relPath!" (
     
         rem Check if the file extension is png jpg or mp4
         if /I "!ext!" == ".png" (
          
         rem If the file extension is png jpg or mp4 copy the file and display a message
         rem echo Copying "%%f" to "%dst%\!relPath!"
         xcopy /y "%%f" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
         
         )else if /I "!ext!" == ".jpg" (
             xcopy /y "%%f" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
         
         )else if /I "!ext!" == ".mp4" (
             xcopy /y "%%f" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
          
         )else (
                 
             rem If the file extension is not png jpg or mp4, create a dummy file
             echo Creating dummy "%%f" to "%dst%\!relPath!"
              
             xcopy /y "%dummy%" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
        )

    )
)
echo Done.
```

The problem seems to be when I store the relative path to the file in relPath, if the filename or any of the subfolders contains a **`!`** then it will ignore everything that goes after the **`!`** but still keeps the file extension somehow. I think, but I am not sure, that even if I would manage to store correctly the path in relPath, I would still have issues when using later on `"%dst%\!relPath!"` in the other parts of the for loop for copying the file or checking if it exists.

How could I get around this?

EDIT: Here is an screenshot showing the result for a very simple scenario:
[image]

EDIT 2:
I tried now with @harrymc suggestion and it seems to have solved partially the issue but some filenames are still giving trouble. New code:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

rem Set the source and destination folders
set "src=L:\folderS\sub1\sub2"
set "dst=L:\folderD\sub1"

rem Set the path to the dummy file that we need to create dummy files with xcopy
set "dummy=L:\dummy.txt"

rem Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
if not exist "%dst%" mkdir "%dst%"

rem Loop through all the files in the source folder
for /R "%src%" %%f in (*) do (

     rem Get the file path
     set "filePath=%%f"
     echo the full path is !filePath!

     rem Get the file extension
     set "ext=%%~xf"
     
     setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
     rem Get the relative path excluding the path until the specified src folder
     set "relPath=!filePath:%src%\=!"
     echo the relative path is !relPath!
     
     rem Check if the file does not exist in the destination
     if not exist "%dst%\!relPath!" (
     
         rem Check if the file extension is png jpg or mp4
         if /I "!ext!" == ".png" (
          
         rem If the file extension is png jpg or mp4 copy the file and display a message
         rem echo Copying "%%f" to "%dst%\!relPath!"
         xcopy /y "%%f" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
         
         )else if /I "!ext!" == ".jpg" (
             xcopy /y "%%f" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
         
         )else if /I "!ext!" == ".mp4" (
             xcopy /y "%%f" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
          
         )else (
                 
             rem If the file extension is not png jpg or mp4, create a dummy file
             echo Creating dummy "%%f" to "%dst%\!relPath!"
              
             xcopy /y "%dummy%" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
        )

    )
    endlocal
)
echo Done.
```

Here is an example of a filename that still give trouble. I think now this is xcopy limitation due to the length of the filename or maybe another symbol.

[image]

EDIT 3: It is fully solved now. The last remaining problem was with the lines

```bat
xcopy /y "%%f" "%dst%\!relPath!*"
```

that should instead be:

```bat
echo F|xcopy "!filePath!" "%dst%\!relPath!"
```

this fixed the problem I was still having with some symbols, and with the "F|" xcopy will not ask me each time if it is a file or not.
There is still probably the limitation of 256 chars for xcopy but I don't see to hit that limit. I could instead use robocopy which would be better but robocopy parameters are quite different and I would need probably quite a few attempts to get it right.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: can you confirm that is the complete batch file, if not edit to add additional relevant code .  Can you provide a simple what I get 'Output is `X`' but I want is `Y`

Comment: @BlindSpots thank you for looking into this. Yes, it is the complete batch file. I added a screenshot at the bottom of my question with a very simple scenario. You will see how it copies in the destination folder L:\folderD\sub1 both files but the second file has the filename a bit changed due to the ! sign. Some file names might have more than one ! character and then instead of just omiting the ! in the destination file it will omit part of the name (the part between 2 exclamation marks). I just want to copy the files with the same name as the source folder.

Comment: Try to use `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` and use percent characters, not exclamation marks.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for the input but I don't think this script can work without using delayed expansion, which would be needed for everything to work properly inside the for loop. I tried already because that's how I initially attempted to build the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the advice in the post
[Escaping exclamation marks with delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264174/escaping-exclamation-marks-with-delayed-expansion),
I have enclosed only the necessary part *inside* the loop with the
`setlocal` commands, and this worked for my example:

```
@echo off
set "src=C:\Temp\tmp9"
for /R "%src%" %%f in (*.txt) do (
     set "filePath=%%f"
     setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
     echo the full path is "!filePath!"
     set "relPath=!filePath:%src%\=!"
     echo relative path is "!relPath!"
     endlocal
)
```

And got this result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks @harrymc I tried this and I did some progress but some filenames are still giving trouble. At the end of the description of the question you will see a new screenshot showing an example. I think the issue now is with some limitations in xcopy. I will try now the approach proposed by lo-ol in a different answer. I plan to give a bounty reward to both of you if that's possible.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation for bounties. The most you can do is upvote both and mark one as accepted.

Comment: I set this as the correct answer since even if it doesn't fully fix everything I needed, it surely solved the problem with the "!" which is what I initially asked. After that I managed to fix the other issues too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

*/ Edit

> *I tried this and I got an error: **"The full path of is too long**. Done."*
> *The longest path is: `L:\folderS\sub1\sub2\Another Test with Even more Symbols and long Name - And also, commas and brakets! (w23) (We,gasg) adsfasdfdas-asdf.png` Which is trully long, but still totally supported by Windows.*

*In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), [the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as **260 characters**.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)*
*A local path is structured in the following order:*    > *drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character.*
*For example, the maximum path on drive `D` is **`"D:\some 256-character path string<NUL>"`** where `"<NUL>"` represents the invisible terminating ^null` character for the current system codepage.*

***Obs.:** The characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.*

---

My system has already enabled support for paths longer than 260 characters, now if your path has more than 260 characters then I suggest you check the information linked in this edition and compare it with the settings on your system and hopefully that resolves this new event.

Note that I had no problems with long path/names, and I even added a screenshot:

[image]

---

- To check from the command line whether long name support
  has been enabled, **`0x1`** or disabled **`0x0`** (default), try:

```bat
E:\>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" /f "LongPathsEnabled"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
   LongPathsEnabled    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

---

- To enable (**`0x1`**) or disable (**`0x0`**) support for long path names on the command line, try:

```bat
:: To enable support for long path names ::
> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" /v "LongPathsEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

:: To  disable support for long path names ::
> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" /v "LongPathsEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

---

---

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
     
set "_src=L:\folderS\sub1\sub2"
set "_dst=L:\folderD\sub1"

robocopy "%_src%" "%_dst%" /e /xf *.* /copy:d | findstr /e \\

for /R "%_src%" %%G in (*) do (
     
     set "_var=%%~fG"
     
     setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
     
     call set "_filePath=!_var:^!=^^!!"
     <con: call set "_rltvPath=%%_filePath:!_src!\=%%"
     <con: call set "_dummyFile=!_rltvPath:%%~xG=.txt!"
     
     call echo\the file path is "!_filePath!"
     call echo\the relative path is "!_rltvPath!"
     call echo\the dummy path file is "!_dummyFile!"
     
     if not exist "%_dst%\!_rltvPath!" (
     
         if /I "%%~xG" == ".png" (
            
             call copy /y "!_filePath!" "%_dst%\!_rltvPath!"
                 
            )else if /I "%%~xG" == ".jpg" (
             
             call copy /y "!_filePath!" "%_dst%\!_rltvPath!"
            
            )else if /I "%%~xG" == ".mp4" (
            
             call copy /y "!_filePath!" "%_dst%\!_rltvPath!"
             
            )else (
             
             call echo\cd.>"%_dst%\!_dummyFile!"
            
            )
            
        )
     
     echo\ & endlocal
     
    )

echo Done. & endlocal
```

---

The main way is, first define the variable, then turn on delayed expansion with escapes in new [substring](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=25881) for the escaped variable, and then when using, use [`call command`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) so that [the realtime delayed escapes do their part](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=25881#p25937).

Comment: @lo-ol I tried this and I got an error:
"The full path of  is too long. Done."

The logest path is:
L:\folderS\sub1\sub2\Another Test with Even more Symbols and long Name - And also, commas and brakets! (w23) (We,gasg) adsfasdfdas-asdf.png

Which is trully long, but still totally supported by Windows. I do have paths that long in practice, in the big folder that I need to copy. I have a similar issue if I try with xcopy after tweaking the code a bit as you can see in the description of the question (I added a new code and new image).

Comment: "lo-ol" Thanks for your help with this and for proposing an approach that uses robocopy which would be indeed an improvement. For now I got it working using xcopy (you can check my last edit in the description of the question) and I am writing you so you don't invest more time on this, unless you still want to propose a solution using robocopy.

Answer (score 1):

#### BAT File

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

rem Set the source and destination folders
set "src=L:\folderS\sub1\sub2"
set "dst=L:\folderD\sub1"

rem Set the path to the dummy file
set "dummy=L:\dummy.txt"

rem Set list of extensions to copy
set "ext=.png .jpg .mp4"

rem loop through all files in source folder and subfolders
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('Dir "%src%" /A:-D /b /s') do (
  
  rem set default dummy flag state (on)
  set "dummyFlag=on"
  
  rem set filepath
  set "filePath=%%f"
  
  rem Get the path to parent relative to %src%
  set "relPath=!filePath:%src%=!"
   
  rem continue if destination file does not exist  
  if not exist "%dst%!relPath!" (
  
    rem compare list of extensions to current file extension
    for %%e in (%ext%) do (
    
      rem if current file extension matches extension from list      
      if "%%~xf" == "%%e" (
      
        xcopy /-I /Q "!filePath!" "%dst%!relPath!*" > nul
        set "dummyFlag=off"
       
      )
       
    )
  
    rem check if dummyFlag is still set 
    if "!dummyFlag!" == "on" (
    
      rem Copy dummy file to destination
      xcopy /-I /Q "%dummy%" "%dst%!relPath!*" > nul

    )

  )

)
```

##### Notes

- `if not exist "%dst%" mkdir "%dst%"` isn't necessary as `xcopy` will create directories as needed
- added a list of extensions to simplify adding and removing extensions and to reduce code duplication `set "ext=.png .jpg .mp4"`
- used a `dir "%src%" /A:-D /b /s` approach to the for loop (list of all (only) files in "%src%" and its subfolders
- added a flag for determining if the file matched one of the extensions `!dummyFlag!=<on/off>`
- modified `xcopy`:

  - removed `/y` switch as no files should be overwritten, otherwise why check `if not exist`
  - added switch `/-I` so if the destination doesn't exist, it is understood to be a file
  - added switch `/Q` don't list filenames to be copied
  - added `> NULL` to suppress completion messages

Comment: Thank you for this. I wish I could give bounty awards to all of you but I had to choose. I already gave the bounty to someone that helped yesterday and marked the reply from harrymc as the correct one since my initial question (the problem with "!") is solved by his reply.
You however are proposing a solution that would probably improve the whole script so I am very grateful for your detailed answer, but yesterday night I managed to make it work on my own way (please check my last edit in the question description)
I get this "Invalid switch - /-I" when I try it, other than that it looks good

Answer (score 0):

Can adding something like this solve the problem ?

```
set filePath=%filePath:!=^^^^!%
```

We will look for all the `!` characters in the path and we replace them with `^!` to neutralize the special character `!` which is certainly causing you these troubles.
You can try varying the number of `^` before the `!` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I understand that this would be inserted right after doing set "filePath=%%f" ?. I am a bit hesitant to try things without knowing what they do exactly since I want to make sure nothing weird happen with my computer files. What is this supposed to do and why exactly four ^ in your example?
The solution would need to be universal and work with a big number of files which may contein none, one or many ! in the file name.

Comment: @Bacomino - “Can adding something like this solve the problem ?” - As the author of this answer you probably should know the answer to that question.

Comment: Hello, can someone please confirm this supposition? The `!` character are interpreted by the system each time it uses the string. Each time the system see a `^` before a `!` character, it's considered like a standard string character, remove the `^` character and return a string with a cleaned `! `. If the string is used x times, you need x `^` to tell x times that's a standard character.